# MOTO TxType with Form Protocol Integration

Tags: opayo

We're attempting to write an application that integrates with SagePay via a web page.  The information will be entered by a sales person as part of a larger application (after taking payment details over the phone from a customer) and we are trying to use the Form Protocol Integration to facilitate this.

After having successfully got this working using the PAYMENT TxType, we discovered that the client requires the transaction type of "MOTO".  This doesn't appear to work by simply changing the TxType field we are sending (and the documentation is pretty explicit about which types are permitted).

Is there an easy way to resolve this without completely changing the way we're integrating with SagePay?  Also, if we do need to use a different API or integration method, is there any documentation on this?  None of the documentation I have found has referenced a "MOTO" TxType.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

TxType will always be PAYMENT.  You can specify the account type with the field AccountType and setting it to M for Moto

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is correct, with the proviso that *Sage Pay Form* does not support the `MOTO` account type. Instead, *Sage Pay Server* should be used. With enough PCI checks, *Sage Pay Direct* could be used, but I would recommend *Server*, as it puts all the CC details capture into a remote form on the Sage Pay gateway.

Answer (score 1):

According to SagePay MOTO can not be implemented for Form Integration. h

Comment: Do you have a link to the source on this?

Comment: http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/account-type-m-everything-you-need-to-know